# Códificar o fechamento de uma aplicação

Tags: java, javafx

Olá, boa tarde a todos!

Eu estou com um problema no software da empresa. Eu criei um serverSocket ao iniciar a aplicação, e com isto consigo controlar para que apenas uma aplicação seja aberta na mesma máquina. Porém, ao fechar o sistema, preciso dar um .close no serverSocket criado, para que fique liberado o acesso ao sistema.

Eu não consigo de forma nenhuma criar um método que seja chamado no ato do fechamento do sistema. Além de controlar o socket, existem inúmeras necessidades que poderiam ser implementadas no fechamento da aplicação. Portanto preciso muito da colaboração de vocês. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua classe principal, ou seja a que estende de `Application` e tem o método `start(Stage stage)` implementado, sobrescreva o método `stop()` e implemente o que desejar nele:

```
@Override
public void stop(){
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Math, olá! Eu fiz da forma como você falou, só que não consigo debugar, a aplicação é desktop, e quando eu fecho (através do X vermelho mesmo) não passa pelo método stop(). De qualquer forma, para necessidade inicial que era fechar o socket criado, pesquisando descobri que ao fechar a aplicação o socket é automaticamente fechado e dispensa essa implementação. Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Mas você consegue debuggar o resto do código? Eu rodei aqui e funcionou ok, inclusive o debug

Comment: Chegou a fazer um build clean antes de debugar? Só pra confirmar, pois não imagino o que mais que pode ser

Comment: Sim, fiz sim, eu removi o comentário pq mandei errado pra vc, olhe:

    private static ServerSocket s;

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (s != null) {
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }
        Platform.exit();
        System.exit(0);
    }